# Why are non case classes allowed to inherit sealed classes?

Tags: scala, inheritance, case-class

I was under the impression that sealed classes mostly serve the purpose that all exhaustive subclasses are written in the same compilation unit (which happens to be a file in Scala).

However, think of the following situation. I've a file called AnimalsPart1.scala, wherein I have the following declarations:

```scala
sealed class Animal
case class Dog() extends Animal
case class Cat() extends Animal
class Herbivore() extends Animal
```

Next, I've a file called AnimalPart2.scala wherein I have the following declaration:

```scala
case class Hen() extends Herbivore
def whatAnimalAmI(a : Animal) = a match {
    case Dog() => "Dog"
    case Cat() => "Cat"
    case Hen() => "Hen"
}
println(whatAnimalAmI(new Hen()))

// prints "Hen" as the output
```

Allowing classes to inherit sealed classes, and then making those classes inheritable everywhere breaks the founding principle of sealed classes. This is a small example, but if the above property holds true, it would be very difficult to list exhaustive set of subclasses for a given sealed class.

Why, therefore, is a non case class allowed to inherit sealed class? Also, how do we deal with the above problem (Hen inheriting an Animal outside the file where the sealed class was declared)?

Comment: `Hen` doesn't inherit from `Animal`, but from `Herbivore`, which is not sealed. Seal only prevent direct inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to prevent a `class` from being subclassed then the mechanism for that is `final`.

The point of a `sealed` class is that all the **direct** subclasses of a `class` or `trait` are in the same file. This allows the compiler to tell if a `match` is exhaustive by seeing if all the direct subclasses are matched.

The `match` in the question does not catch `Herbivore` or other subclasses of `Herbivore` so the compiler knows that it is not exhaustive (and may give a warning).

Answer (score 1):

> Allowing classes to inherit sealed classes, and then making those classes inheritable everywhere breaks the founding principle of sealed classes

The principle is that matching against direct subtypes (and the class itself if it isn't abstract) is exhaustive, in this case

```
def whatAnimalAmI(a : Animal) = a match {
    case Dog() => "Dog"
    case Cat() => "Cat"
    case h: Herbivore => "Herbivore"
}
```

This way you don't need to look at any other files and find that `Herbivore` has some subclasses. So this principle isn't broken.

Now, it's true that you can match inexhaustively too, but you could do that even if `Herbivore` were a case class (or sealed) by omitting it.